# Stateless webapi fails when published

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I just tried to publish an out-of-the-box stateless webapi service to an Azure SF cluster.
Locally it runs fine, but once published, I can't seem to reach http://mysfcluster.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8820/api/values

Do I need to declare the port in an other place then in the ServiceManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare it in the "Custom endpoints" section when creatin the node type.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services/